# STRINGdb r environment; error in plot_network

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `stringdb` in R and i'm getting the following error when i try to plot the network:

> Error in if (grepl("The document has moved", res)) { :    argument is
> of length zero

code:

```
library(STRINGdb)
#(specify organism)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new( version="10", species=9606, score_threshold=0)

filt_mapped = string_db$map(filt, "GeneID", removeUnmappedRows = TRUE)

head(filt_mapped)
```

(i have columns titled: GeneID, logFC, FDR, STRING_id with 156 rows)

```
filt_mapped_hits = filt_mapped$STRING_id
head(filt_mapped_hits)
```

(156 observations)

```
string_db$plot_network(filt_mapped_hits, add_link = FALSE)
```

> Error in if (grepl("The document has moved", res)) { :     argument is
> of length zero

Comment: I am having the same issue. Help!

Answer (score 2):

You are using quite few years old version of Bioconductor and by extension the STRING package.
If you update to the newest one, it will work. However the updated package only supports only the latest version STRING (currently version 11), so the underlying network may change a bit.

More detailed reason is this:

The STRING's hardware infrastructure underwent recently major changes which forced a different server setup.
Now all the old calls are forwarded to a different URL, however the cURL call, how it was implemented, does not follow our redirects which breaks the STRINGdb package functionality.
We cannot update the old bioconductor package and our server setup can’t be really changed.

That said, the fix for an old version is relatively simple.
In STRINGdb library there is script with all the methods "rstring.r".

In there you’ll find “get_png” method. In it replace this line:

```
urlStr = paste("http://string-db.org/version_", version, "/api/image/network", sep="" )
```

With this line:

```
urlStr = paste("http://version", version, ".string-db.org/api/image/network", sep="" )
```

Load the library again and it should create the PNG, as before.

Comment: What do you mean by “cURL library does not follow our redirects”? curl *can* of course follow redirects when used correctly.

Comment: Of course it does, but in default settings it doesn't and that was used in the original code. The issue is a bit different no? However it was written the old code can't be fixed  in the repository. But that is a good point, I have rephrased the original answer that it is not an issue with cURL, but our call.